# Tooltip hide/show doesn't work in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3 and have a button and input. I would like to show tooltip if button is disabled and hide tooltip if type of button is submit. In my snippet `.tooltip('hide')` method doesn't work and I don't know why.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyx5jjtt/5/)

**html**

```
    <div class=" user-attributes">
<input type="text" name="attrName" />

    <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please select attribute name" class="btn btn-default disabled" name="addAttribute" >Add attribute</button>

    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
    $('button[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'bottom',
});
/* allow bootstrap tooltip for disabled buttons */
$('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', 'auto');  

$( ".user-attributes [name='attrName']" ).bind('input', function(){
    var inputIsEmpty = $(this).val().length < 1;
    if (inputIsEmpty){
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').addClass('disabled');
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('type');
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
        $('button[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
    } else {
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('style');
        $('.user-attributes button[type="submit"]').attr('type', 'submit');
        $('button[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tooltip('destroy');` helped.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyx5jjtt/21/)